# IFERROR function breaking if a row has the same item in a different row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idg5w.png)
[Table with Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aun0s.png)

If I throw in an item that is identical one of the rows, it wont autofill the whole row.

Under the A column, I have the code CW01 which refers to the product Carcass White variant STD from a table with all the products.
The way it works is, If I type that code, the Product Type, Product and Variant Column automatically fill in.

If I type that Code in another row it wont Autofill because the Code is already in a different row.

Currently I have a formula in that spills to the rows below for every item I pop in.

In Column
A: it's a Data Validation Code

B: =IFERROR(FILTER(Table55[Categorie],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table55[Code],A4:A20,0))),"")

C: =IFERROR(FILTER(Table55[Product],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table55[Code],A4:A20,0))),"")

D: =IFERROR(FILTER(Table55[Variant],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table55[Code],A4:A20,0))),"")

I: =IFERROR(FILTER(Table55[Price],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table55[Product]&Table55[Variant],C4:C20&D4:D20,0)))*TOCOL(H4:H20,1)," ")

Comment: Please edit your question to post your data as text. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Off topic, but: Filter has a built in IFNA argument, so the IFERROR is not required `=IFERROR(FILTER(Table55[Categorie],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table55[Code],A4:A20,0))),"")` is the same as `=FILTER(Table55[Categorie],ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table55[Code],A4:A20)),"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XLOOKUP()`, i.e.

```
=XLOOKUP(TOCOL(A4:A20,1),Table55[Code],Table55[Categorie]," ")
```

in `B4`

```
=XLOOKUP(TOCOL(A4:A20,1),Table55[Code],Table55[Product]," ")
```

in `C4` and

```
=XLOOKUP(TOCOL(A4:A20,1),Table55[Code],Table55[Variant]," ")
```

in `D4`

The formula in `I4` should also be updated to

```
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(TOCOL(A4:A20,1),Table55[Code],Table55[Price])*TOCOL('Form'!H4:H20,1)," ")
```

[image: Screenshot illustrating spilling formula]

Comment: The formula for I4 is pretty much doing that same thing, but I did use yours since its shorter, however the other 3 give me a #Calc Empty Array error and I also have to individually put them on all the cells instead of having them spill.

Comment: @Aloosh I've added a screenshot to show that the formulae **do** spill (if you have an empty array then you should wrap the function in an IFERROR() function - the `XLOOKUP()` function _itself_ already handles errors for values not found)

Comment: My comment on FILTER having a built in error handling goes for XLOOKUP too. No need for IFERROR